# Free List Allocator with Red Black Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory-management, red-black-tree

I'm trying to implement a free list allocator using Red Black Tree for optimize `O(LogN)` best fit search.

My strategy is that when a block is allocated, it's allocated with a `Header` where

```cpp
struct Header {
  std::size_t m_Size;
};
```

thus `sizeof(Header) == sizeof(std::size_t)`
This is done, so when deallocating I could know how much bytes were allocated to give it back as a free node.

Now there's a problem with this solution, because now I have to align the `Header` itself + the allocated block to the requested alignment, so padding in between the `Header` and the allocated block start, and padding between the end of the allocated block and a start of a new `Header` (so next block `Header` will be already aligned) are needed.

So to illustrate the problem better here's a Red Black Tree with nodes indicating free block sizes minus `sizeof(Header)`
[image]

Now let's assume a user allocate a block of size 16 with alignment of 16:

```cpp
allocate(16, 16);
```

Now best fit will yield us node 17.
But we can't count on it, let's assume node 17 is at address `0x8` and we're on x32 so `sizeof(Header) = 4`.
`Header`'s address will be from `0x8-0xC`, now we would need to add a padding so our block will be aligned to 16 as requested, this padding is equal to 4 bytes so our allocated block will start at `0x10` which is aligned to 16. Now no padding is needed at the end of the block since `0x10` + `16d` will be aligned to next block `Header`.
The padding between the end of the allocated block to the start of the new block is easy to calculate before-hand like so:

```cpp
std::size_t headerPadding = size % sizeof(Header) != 0 ? sizeof(Header) - size % sizeof(Header) : 0;
```

So it's not dependent on the address of the free node.
But the padding between the end of the `Header` and the start of the allocated block **IS** dependent on the address of the free node like I've demonstrated.
And for our example the total needed size in the case of this specific node will be 4 (padding between `Header` and allocated block) + 16 (allocated block size) + 0 (padding needed for next free block header alignment) = 20.
Obviously node 17 doesn't match.

Now my strategy to fix this is as follows:
- Find best fit
- See if best fit matches the size requirements as described
- If yes we're done
- If not get its successor and check if it matches the size requirements as described
- If yes we're done
- If not start over from successor parent until we reach a node that satisfy size requirements or we reach the original best fit again

Here's a code describing the process:

```cpp
void FreeTreeAllocator::Find(const std::size_t size, const std::size_t alignment, std::size_t& sizePadding, std::size_t& headerPadding, RBTree::Node*& curr)
{
    headerPadding = size % sizeof(Header) != 0 ? sizeof(Header) - size % sizeof(Header) : 0;

    RBTree::Node* best = m_Tree.SearchBest(m_Tree.m_Root, size + headerPadding);
    RBTree::Node* origin = best;

    std::vector<std::size_t> visited;

    while (visited[visited.size() - 1] != (std::size_t)origin && !IsNodeBigEnough(size, alignment, sizePadding, headerPadding, best))
    {
        RBTree::Node* successor = m_Tree.Successor(best);
        if (IsNodeBigEnough(size, alignment, sizePadding, headerPadding, successor))
        {
            best = successor;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::vector<std::size_t>::iterator it;
            do {
                best = successor->m_Parent;
                it = std::find(visited.begin(), visited.end(), (std::size_t)best);
            } while (it != visited.end());
        }
        visited.push_back((std::size_t)best);
    }
}

bool FreeTreeAllocator::IsNodeBigEnough(const std::size_t size, const std::size_t alignment, std::size_t& sizePadding, std::size_t& headerPadding, RBTree::Node* curr)
{
    if (curr == m_Tree.m_Nil)
        return false;
    void* currentAddress = reinterpret_cast<char*>(curr) + sizeof(Header);
    std::size_t space = curr->m_Value;
    std::align(alignment, size, currentAddress, space);
    sizePadding = reinterpret_cast<char*>(currentAddress) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(curr) - sizeof(Header);
    return sizePadding + size + headerPadding <= curr->m_Value;
}
```

Now for the given allocation request:

```cpp
allocate(16, 16);
```

and the given example tree from the picture the following the algorithm described, the search path will be:

```
17 -> 21 -> 22 -> 23 -> 25 -> 27
```

At worst case this is `O(LogN + M)` where `M` is the size of the right sub-tree of the original best fit node.

Now one way this could be solved if I make `sizeof(Header)` = `sizeof(std::max_align_t)`, this way the padding between the `Header` and the start of the allocated block will always be 0, so we won't need this padding anymore because every request will be aligned without this padding, so we could really just do:

```cpp
void FreeTreeAllocator::Find(const std::size_t size, std::size_t& headerPadding, RBTree::Node*& curr)
{
    headerPadding = size % sizeof(Header) != 0 ? sizeof(Header) - size % sizeof(Header) : 0;

    RBTree::Node* best = m_Tree.SearchBest(m_Tree.m_Root, size + headerPadding);
    return best;
```

But that will waste alot of memory compared to my proposed idea where I settle on `O(LogN + M)` best fit search.

Now why do I ask it?
Because I see the use of Red Black Tree as optimization for free list allocator to reduce best fit search to `O(LogN)` while I can't seem to make it really `O(LogN)`, the flaw with my design I guess is that there need to be a `Header` for book-keeping on how much bytes to give back to a free block when deallocating, and I don't see a way to do it without this, if I was able to not have a `Header` at all, or make it so I don't have issues with it's alignment to find padding specific for a node in the list (by making `sizeof(Header)` = `sizeof(std::max_align_t)`, or even `sizeof(Header)` = `1`) then this could be solved with simple `O(LogN)` search.

I'm looking for ideas on how to solve this issue, how other implementations are doing this in `O(LogN)` while keeping inner fragmentation as low as possible?

**UPDATE**:
I ended up having the node addresses aligned to `alignof(std::max_align_t) - sizeof(Header)` so that makes `Header` always aligned no matter if you're on x32/x64 (remember that `Header` is composed of `sizeof(std::size_t)`), and no matter if `alignof(std::max_align_t)` is 8 or 16.
That makes the allocated payload to start at address that is aligned to `alignof(std::max_align_t)` just like `malloc`, so no matter what is allocated it will always be aligned to the max alignment and no padding is required between `Header` and payload.
The only padding required is after payload to match the next address that is aligned to `alignof(std::max_align_t) - sizeof(Header)` + any padding required to make it so the allocated block is at least `sizeof(RBTree::Node)` bytes big (including `sizeof(Header)` inside the equation) so when deallocation we could safely store an `RBTree::Node` without overriding other data.
Without the padding between `Header` and the payload, and with the padding needed to align next block to `alignof(std::max_align_t) - sizeof(Header)` we can easily use the default `RBTree::Search` of `O(LogN)` since the padding can be calculated beforehand depending on the size of the block and removing from the equation the start address of a particular node.

The only remaining problem I have with optimizing this free list allocator to `O(LogN)` is the deallocation part, more precisely the coalescence part.
What I can't solve now is how to do `O(1)` coalescence. I rearranged the `RBTree::Node` struct such as that `m_Parent` is first and so its LSB is always set 1 (for every function relying on `m_Parent` I have a getter function for fixing it) and then I can check if next block of current deallocated block (we can get to next block with size from `Header`) if the first `sizeof(std::size_t)` bytes `& 0x1` is true and if so it's a free node, if not it's a busy block with `Header` (since `Header`'s `m_Size` LSB will always be 0 because we add padding for alignment with `std::max_align_t`).
The remaining problem is how to get to the previous memory block and know if it's free or busy, that I cannot figure yet and would love to hear suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete answer is my OP update and this answer.
I found a solution for coalescence in `O(1)`.
My OP update describe how we can achieve coalescence with next block in `O(1)` but not how to achieve coalescence in `O(1)` with previous block.
To do this I store an additional `std::size_t m_PrevSize` in both busy block `Header` struct and `RBTree::Node` struct as **the first member**.
When a block is allocated and becomes busy (either by simple allocation or by block splitting) I simply move to the next block using the `Header`'s `m_Size` property and the first `std::size_t` bytes to 0. This will set the next memory block either busy or free that the previous is busy and there's no need to merge with.
When a block is deallocated and I convert it to free block, I do the same thing but set the first `std::size_t` bytes to `RBTree::Node`'s `m_Value` property which is basically how much bytes this free block have, and the when deallocating I can check own `m_PrevSize` property and if it's not 0 go backward `m_PrevSize` bytes and do the merge.

Comment: I am also looking into writing a free list allocator with an rb tree. do you by any change have an open source version of your allocator ?

Comment: @Ody yes I have made an allocator library under MIT license which you can find here
https://github.com/Kashio/A5
Hope this can help you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will have a look:)

Answer (score 0):

For the padding issue:

Make sure the size of your free list nodes is a power of 2 -- either 16 or 32 bytes -- and make sure the addresses of your free list nodes are all aligned at `node_size * x - sizeof(Header)` bytes.

Now all of your allocations will automatically be aligned at multiples of the node size, with no padding required.

Allocations requiring larger alignments will be rare, so it might be reasonable just to find the left-most block of appropriate size, and walk forward in the tree until you find a block that works.

If you need to optimize large-alignment allocations, though, then you can sort the blocks first by size, and then break ties by sorting on the number of zeros at the right of each nodes's allocation address (node address + sizeof(Header)).

Then, a single search in the tree will either find an exactly-fitting block that works, or a larger block.  There is a good chance you'll be able to split the larger block in a way that satisfies the alignment requirement, but if not, then you can again skip ahead in the tree to find a block of that size that works, or an even larger block, etc.

The resulting search is faster, but still not guaranteed O(log N).  To fix that, you can just give up after a limited number of skips forward, and revert to finding a block of `requested_size + requested_alignment`.  If you find one of those, then it is guaranteed that you'll be able to split it up to satisfy your alignment constraint.

Comment: I ended up having the node addresses aligned to `alignof(std::max_align_t) - sizeof(Header)` so that makes `Header` also always aligned no matter if you're on x32/x64 (`sizeof(std::size_t)`), and no matter if `alignof(std::max_align_t)` is 8 or 16. So that makes the allocated block start at address that is aligned to `alignof(std::max_align_t)` just like malloc, so no matter what is allocated it will always be aligned and no padding is required between `Header` and payload.

Comment: The only padding required is after payload to match the next address that is aligned to `alignof(std::max_align_t) - sizeof(Header)` + any padding required to make it so the allocated block is at least `sizeof(RBTree::Node)` bytes big (including `sizeof(Header)` inside the equation).

Comment: What I can't solve now is how to do `O(1)` `Coalescence`.
I rearranged the `RBTree::Node` struct such as that `m_Parent` is first and so its LSB is always 1 (have getter function for fixing it) and then I can check if next block of current deallocated block (we can get to next block with size from `Header`) if the first `sizeof(std::size_t)` bytes `& 0x1` is true and if so it's a free node if not it's a busy block with `Header` (since `Header` size LSB will always be 0 because we add padding for alignment). The problem is how to get to the previous memory block and know if it's free or busy.

Answer (score 0):

> there need to be a Header for book-keeping on how much bytes to give back to a free block when deallocating

On a 64-bit platform, one way to eliminate the header is to make your allocator manage arenas of power-of-2 object sizes. Each arena is for one object size and all arenas are of the same size. Then map (reserve only) one large chunk of virtual memory in such a way, that it is aligned by its own size (which is also a power of 2). That way, your pointers to objects are structured: the lower order bits are the offset to the object within the arena, the next bits are the arena number. For each arena it needs to maintain the free list and allocated object count, but the free lists must initially include only one page or 1 object (whichever is bigger), so that it doesn't commit page frames to the entire reserved virtual memory, which would run out of memory immediately.

For example, if you have 8GiB arenas for objects of power-2-sizes from 8 to 65536 bytes, then the lower [0:32] bits are the object offset within the arena, bits [33:36] are the arena number and log2 of object size (arenas [0, 2] are unused because they are not big enough for free list next pointer).

Comment: Sounds to me just like multiple pool allocators that support allocation of power of 2 sizes and then the "free list allocator" will become just a proxy allocator to point each request to the correct pool allocator, correct me if I'm wrong? Also if that's the case there're a few disadvantages I can think of compared to classic free list allocator implementation. For example if you want to iterate for some reason over the allocated objects in your free list allocator, with your approach spatial locality will be much lower leading to more cache misses because each arena is potentially somewhere

Comment: else, and even if all arena are one big contiguous memory block, each object might be far away from each other causing more cache line loads.
I know this is weird reason maybe to think about, but I don't have really purpose for this allocator, more of a general purpose development, so I don't want to restrict my allocator with "hacky" implementations that might cause end user unexpected result.

Comment: @Jorayen I understand the words, but I couldn't understand your concerns, apart from not being able to iterate over allocated blocks, which isn't something I ever needed.

Comment: I'm trying to develop it as part of a libray.
An end user might expect items to be close in memory regardless of how big the allocation size was, all he needs to know that he uses a free list allocator and while your solution will work it'll have maybe undesired properties for some people. That's why I'm going with the more traditional implementation of using rb tree.

Comment: @Jorayen It can be argued that in the allocation function there is no information whether the user would benefit from subsequent allocation requests to be allocated close together, so that always doing that is a hit and miss. For ultimate performance critical data structures and collections are manually allocated with desired cache alignment and memory layout and no housekeeping information in between objects because that makes CPU cache utilization worse. Also, red-black trees are CPU cache unfriendly data structures, which are better avoided in performance critical code.

Comment: Well just using a custom allocator is a hint by itself that data might be close to each other (one of the reasons to develop custom allocators). Now the proximity factor can depend from implementation to implementation and I agree on that, but I prefer to keep mine as close as possible, and since free list allocator, unlike pool allocator, can operate on any size request, then house keeping is a must. Also red black tree are not CPU cache friendly I agree, but with the right optimization they can benefit this task, since they allow `O(LogN)` allocation and deallocation

Comment: and if stored on the memory arena allocated by the allocator itself, this will reduce cache misses.